# MySQL connection issue after refactor query with parameters

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net

I am trying to refactor my code with parameterized queries.

The code is attempting to insert data into a MySQL database, based on two textboxes - student_lastname and student_name. But seems I am making some sort of mistake in the connection.

This is my attempt below:

```
static string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SchoolGrades.Properties.Settings.ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

private void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string sqlCommand = 
        "INSERT INTO OceniStudents(student_name, student_lastname) + " +
                           "VALUES(?student_name, ?student_lastname);";

    try
    {
        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conString))
        {
            MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(sqlCommand, con);
            cmdDatabase.Prepare();
            cmdDatabase.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("student_name", this.txtStudentName));
            cmdDatabase.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("student_lastname", this.txtStudentLastName));

            MySqlDataReader myReader;
            myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();

            MessageBox.Show("Data is inserted.", "Notice", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

But once I call the method - btnNew_Click - I get an error: `The connection is not open`.

I've double checked - the connection string, server, database, table is all set.

Any ideas what am I missing?

Comment: Not sure why somebody downvoted the question. I guess we are only supposed to consider issues worthy of Turing award here. Yes, it was a simple mistake. But im still quite new to the language..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creation of connection object, you should open connection with `Open` function.

```
....
using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conString))
{
    con.Open();
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Youre missing the `con.Open();` inyour code

```
try { using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conString)) { con.Open(); MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(sqlCommand, con); cmdDatabase.Prepare(); cmdDatabase.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("student_name", this.txtStudentName)); cmdDatabase.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("student_lastname", this.txtStudentLastName)); MySqlDataReader myReader; myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader(); MessageBox.Show("Data is inserted.", "Notice", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information); } }
```